# Jquery: masonry('hide',element) method with a jquery element

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

So, I'm using Masonry to make a "fluid" layout in my site but now I've encountered a problem involving its hide and reveal methods.

In an event, I'm making this call:

```
$container.masonry('hide', $(this));
```

As you can see, I'm using `$(this)` to  tell masonry what element to hide through jquery

But apparently, this method does not work with a jquery element?

The error message in my console looks like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'hide' (masonry.pkgd.min.js:9)
```

I tried looking in the [documentation](http://desandro.com/masonry/methods.html#hide) but all it says about the accepted type is:

```
$container.masonry( 'hide', items )
```

> **items** Type: *Array* of *Masonry.Items*

What is a *Masonry.Item* supposed to be? And how do I indicate my element as one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation then you find `items` are the `array` of `elements`.

**items**  `Type: Array of Masonry.Items`

Try this,

```
var arr=new Array();
arr.push($(this));
$container.masonry('hide', arr);
```

Comment: Thanks! It hides my items perfectly... but then... I'm trying to use its counterpart 'masonry('reveal', arr)', but now it returns the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reveal' "

Comment: I ended up quitting on using the plugin methods and now I'm just using jquery standard .show() and .hide(), and calling the masonry('layout') method later -.-

Comment: Wow Thanks @XuxuBelezA I was looking around for a decent solution to quirky behaviour with the hide function and your suggestion to just use jquery hide and show really solved my problem and sped up my day! It's not technically the answer to the question but it should be more visible on this topic I think!

Answer (score 0):

Add this function

```
// FIX para Masonry
// goes through all children again and gets bricks in proper order
Outlayer.prototype.publicItemize = function() {
  // collection of item elements
  return this._itemize( this.element.children );
};
```

now you can do this

```
// Get correcto list in correct format
var _list = container.masonry("publicItemize");
// Actions on "_list"
// hide elements
container.masonry("hide", _list);
```